# Simple modulo congruence operation

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Find a number $n$, with $0 \leq n < 15$, so that $6 \times 7$ is congruent to $n$ modulo $15$

Please explain your work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$6 \times 7 = 42 = 12 + 30 \equiv 12 \pmod{15}$

Comment: How did you come to conclusion that 12+30 = 12 (mod 15)

Comment: $30 = 2 \times 15$ so $12 + 30 = 12 + 2 \times 15 \equiv 12 \pmod{15}$.